# How to construct the complex Fourier series of a function over a non-symmetric interval?

Tags: fourier-series

I need to calculate the coefficients $$c_n=\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^Lf(x)e^{-\frac{in\pi x}{L}}dx,\qquad n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\cdots$$ of the complex Fourier series for the function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}-x\ &0<x<1,\\ x\ &1<x<2,\\
\end{cases}$$
but clearly this function is not defined over an interval of the form $(-L,L)$, but $(0,2)$.

I already know that, for the trigonometric real Fourier series, I can fix  this by projecting the function in a certain way over $(-2,0)$, making $f(x)$ an ever, odd or periodic function.
I thought I could use this for my case, but how do I apply this for the complex series?
Do I need to "re-transform" $$e^{-\frac{in\pi x}{L}}=\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)?$$

Comment: The function is periodic.  You can always integrate over a symmetric interval if you like.  That being said, $2L$ is just the period of the function, so you can replace it with the period.

Comment: @XanderHenderson So I suppose that my $f$ is periodic over the interval $(-2,2)$, to make the period and the limit $2L=2,\ L=1$?

Comment: What do you mean "So I suppose that my function is periodic over the interval $(-2,2)$"?  The function you describe is defined on the interval $(0,2)$, is periodic on $\mathbb{R}$, and has period $2$.  Integrate over $[0,2]$, $[-1,1]$, or any other interval of length $2$.  In this context, yes, $L=1$.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that $$c_n = \frac{1}{P} \int_{a}^{a+P} f(x) \mathrm{e}^{2\pi n x / P} \,\mathrm{d}x, $$ where $P$ is the period of the function, and $a$ is any real number.  That is, you can find the Fourier coefficients by integrating over *any* interval of length $P$; because the function is periodic, it doesn't matter which interval you integrate over.

Comment: I would take $L=1$ and extend $f(x) = f(x+2)$ for $x \in [-1,0]$.